# Tag Array Sorting issue

Tags: php, wordpress

10/25/2012 - Still Not solved! Please see below:

My client has a WordPress Tag Cloud (tag array) with tags which include ["] character as well as [The] prefix for some tags. I.e:

```
"rose"
"autumn"
The Abby
The Cloud
The Elephant
```

Obviously all the tags enclosed in the quotations marks ["] are sorted on the top of the list and all the words starting with [The] prefix are sorted somewhere around the letter [T] (following the logical ASC order).

It was sprinkled on me that:  "All tags (in the WP tag cloud) have to be ordered Ascending but those which contain the [" "] or [The] characters have to be sorted with all other tags in the chronological order, ignoring the ["] and [The] prefix.

I looked into the WP core function:

```
**function wp_generate_tag_cloud**
```

but I have no idea where to start. In the raw SQL statement, I could probably use the trim() to filter out the [" "] and [The] characters form the tag cloud array but that is only a thought which I have no idea how to apply.

Comment: Do you want to sort them in MySQL or PHP?

Comment: I guess either way is fine as long as I can hook it up to the WP [wp_generate_tag_cloud] core function. The question is not how to make the MySQL query ignore the selected characters and consequently sort them (ORDER BY) ASC, the issue is how to integrate "any" good solution into the WP platform. Thank you.

Comment: Couldnt you just update the database table and remove both the quotes and the article? Then add something like a filter in the tag form to remove these things for newly created tags?

Comment: @VadimAshikhman I think the tags are meant to have the quotes so removing them would not be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_generate_tag_cloud()` invokes a filter named `tag_cloud_sort`, which can override the sort order specified in the `$args` parameter. The `tag_cloud_sort` filter receives an array of tags and the actual `$args` parameter passed to `wp_generate_tag_cloud()`, so it can inspect the full settings of the `wp_generate_tag_cloud()` invocation and adjust its behavior accordingly.

You could try something like this:

```
function custom_tag_sort($tags, $args) {
    if ($args['orderby'] != 'name') {
        // do not reorder if sort order is not by name.
        // wp_generate_tag_cloud() is smart enough to notice order
        // is not changed and will proceed with its regular sort logic.
        return $tags;
    }
    uasort($tags, 'custom_tag_sort_compare');
}

function custom_tag_sort_compare($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp(
        custom_tag_sort_normalize($a->name),
        custom_tag_sort_normalize($b->name)
    );
}

function custom_tag_sort_normalize($tag) {
    // strip quote marks
    $tag = trim($tag, '"');
    // strip leading definitive article
    $tag = preg_replace('/^\s*the\s+/i', '', $tag);
    return $tag;
}

add_filter('tag_cloud_sort', 'custom_tag_sort');
```

Disclaimer: I've written this after only a cursory inspection of the [`wp_generate_tag_cloud()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/category-template.php#L607) function. I haven't tested it on a live WordPress installation; I have only verified that the sorting function works correctly on your sample tag cloud:

```
The Abby
"autumn"
The Cloud
The Elephant
"rose"
```

Comment: Hi there, this looks promising. I have included it into the functions.php file. It does not seem to work yet but let me play around with it a I will vote you up if this would bring me on the right path. Thank you!

Comment: ..OK, I will vote this up even though I still did not make this work in my script since I am not sorting by 'name' but returning an array instead i.e.: wp_tag_cloud('format=array')

Comment: The default for the `orderby` argument to both `wp_tag_cloud` and `wp_generate_tag_cloud` is `name`, so if you call `wp_tag_cloud('format=array')` you will still get sorting by name in `wp_generate_tag_cloud`. My implementation only avoids incorrect sorting if `wp_generate_tag_cloud` is _explicitly_ called with a different sorting order.

Answer (score 2):

ok so you want to avoid modifying the core code of wordpress... when your client hits the update button after you told him not to, then your going to have to go in and mess with it again.. use action hooks instead. there is conveniently one for hooking into the output for the tag cloud function. add this to your themes functions file

```
function tagCloudFilter($tagCloudString, $args)
{
    $tagCloudString = str_replace('The','', $tagCloudString);
    $tagCloudString = str_replace('"','', $tagCloudString);
}

add_filter('wp_tag_cloud', 'tagCloudFilter', 10, 2);
```

That will atleast get rid of the stuff you dont want. as far as sorting it im not to sure but this should get you on your way. it may be easier to sort it with jquery

If you really want to modify the core code run a foreach loop in the tag array before its formatted and use the str_replaces from above in that loop.. The just run sort() on that array and you should be good. But if it were me i would go with the half solution and not have it alphabetized than to modify the wordpress core

Comment: PART 1: Hi; thank you. Your comment makes sense and I agree that the last thing I would wanted to do is to modify the core, forcing myself to remember the changes every time WP needs to update. That being said, the str_replace action hook is a great solution. However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to hook into the "function wp_generate_tag_cloud" properly so the SQL query gets modified as well. For example, I could somehow append the current MySQL query with the clause ....ORDER BY TRIM( LEADING 'The ' FROM (slug) ). (I did not test it, I am just ...

Comment: PART 2: ...cooking it from the top of my head) but HOW? Also, when I use the str_replace it will literally filter out (replace) the characters which from the array values which I still need to still retain. Any further thoughts ?  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought:

you could copy the original tag_cloud function and create your own on your functions.php.

You make the changes you want to make and add this filter inside the function:

```
$return = apply_filters( 'YOUR_tag_cloud_function', $return, $args );
```

And then create the previous filter to add your function to the hook:

```
add_filter('wp_tag_cloud', 'YOUR_tag_cloud_function');
```

I don't know if it works, I didn't test it. What do you think?